# Translation with resource files, Internationalization asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internationalization, translation

i have an asp.net mvc application, and i use data annotations for data validations
something like this:

```
 public class Booking
 {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
     ...
```

so this is in my DomainModel and i need to **translate** the **ErrorMessage**, and to use the translation in my views

i would like to have just one resource file for each language

anybody knows some solutionus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your error messages in resource files, and apply `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` instead of `ErrorMessage` on the `Required` attribute. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute_members.aspx

Comment: how is it going to know wich language to pick, these classes are in the data model which is a separate class library (not in UI)

Comment: Maybe you can inject some sort of user context?